# How can I get the "realm" value of a SVN repository?

Tags: java, svn, config, svnkit

To my knowledge, when working with SVN repositories there exists a file called "svnserve.conf", which among its properties there exist the "realm" value.

If you have a local repository, I guess you can create this file and then set this value.

My question is this, if I'm using an SVN repository of a third party provider; how can I get the "realm" value using SVNKit in Java? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I've not used SVNKit before, but it looks like the realm is provided to an instance of [`ISVNAuthenticationManager`](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/auth/ISVNAuthenticationManager.html), which you can implement.  There's also [`BasicAuthenticationManager`](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/auth/BasicAuthenticationManager.html) which you might use as a reference.

You can use [`SVNRepository.setAuthenticationManager()`](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/io/SVNRepository.html#setAuthenticationManager(org.tmatesoft.svn.core.auth.ISVNAuthenticationManager)) to specify a `ISVNAuthenticationManager` of your choosing that captures the realm and other information you might need.